# Questions regarding Complex Analysis (Princeton lectures) theorem 1.2

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Complex Analysis (Princeton lectures)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691113858) and I'm struggling to understand one of the theorems in the beginning on sets in the complex plane. It's probably really simple, but I can't get my head around what it means. They define a set $\Omega$ to be **compact** when it's closed and bounded. Then they state the following:

> ...as in the case of real variables, one can prove the following.
>
> **Theorem 1.2** The set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact if and only if every sequence
> $\{z_n\} \subset \Omega$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $\Omega$.

1. Does $\{z_n\} \subset \Omega$ mean that the entire sequence is contained within $\Omega$ (i.e. a subset)?
2. What does "a subsequence that converges to a point in $\Omega$" mean intuitively, because I simply don't understand it.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could rephrase the whole theorem in a intuitive way, since I'm quite a beginner.

Comment: 1. means that $z_n \in \Omega$. 2. means that there is an increasing sequence $n_k$ of integers and a $y \in \Omega$ with $z_{n_k} \rightarrow y$ in the natural sense. Exactly like for compact subsets of the real line.

Comment: $(0,1]$ is not a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ because $\{\frac1n\}$ converges to $0\notin(0,1]$

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz Yes! Thank you, this was the example I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple
$D=\{z:|z|\le 1 \}$ is compact because
We choose any squence as in theorem.
But $G=D/\{0\}$ is not compact. Because if we choose $z_n=z-z^{\frac{1}{n}}$
We can't choose subsequence converges to a point in $G$